# Mechanics of Stygian Slayer's Shadowy Mist Form

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am GMing a Pathfinder game and one of the players is playing a [Stygian Slayer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classOptions/slayer.html#stygian-slayer). I found the section in the Advanced Class Guide describing the Shadowy Mist Form class feature to be too brief and, therefore, ambiguous. Does the mist occupy only the volume of the Slayer's gaseous body or does it fill a volume with a 20ft radius around the Slayer like the way fog cloud works? If it fills the 20ft radius volume then how does the mist move around with the Slayer? Is the Slayer always in the center of it or can they move around independently of the mist?

I have done a bit of Googling but have failed to find answers to these questions and I was wondering if someone could provide some errata that I have been missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that it would only occupy the volume of the Stygian Slayer's gaseous body, as the class ability states that it functions as [Gaseous Form](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/gaseousForm.html), not fog cloud. Neither the class ability nor the spell indicate anything about filling a 20 ft radius volume like fog cloud, just that it obscures vision.

Comment: I think this is very raisinable

Comment: This was my first impression but it seemed then that so little concealment would be generated that the obscuring mist would make Shadowy Mist Form worse than Gaseous Form. Still, this could very well be the way the ability was written to work.

Comment: @1000000000 The ability *is* as terrible as you think it is, and made even terribler by the stygian slayer's inability to dismiss the effect until 1 min. has passed. A truly insulting ability for a 10th-level character.

Comment: That's too bad. The Stygian Slayer was otherwise looking like a neat archetype.

Comment: @HeyICanChan and only when *exactly* one minute has passed or they have to wait a full nother minute.

Comment: It dosn't mean that you can't dispel it until one minute has passed. It just means that if you use it for 30 seconds and dispel it before, it counts as 1 minute for the usage per day.

Comment: @Patrick The special ability says, "These *minutes* need not be consecutive, but must be *used* in 1-minute increments." (Emphasis mine.) Although the spell *gaseous form* has a Duration that's (D)ismissable, it's arguable whether the stygian slayer's special ability's duration--which implicitly replaces the spell's listed Duration--keeps its (D)ismissability. (But, as this *is* arguable, it *would* make an interesting question with potentially wide-ranging implications.)

Answer (score 4):

The text is concise, but not ambiguous.

> Shadowy Mist Form (Sp): At 10th level, a stygian slayer can transform into an inky black cloud of mist. This functions as *gaseous form*, except it also obscures vision as *fog cloud*. The slayer can use this ability for a number of minutes per day equal to his level. These minutes need not be consecutive, but must be used in 1-minute increments. This ability replaces the advanced slayer talent gained at 10th level.

That means it does this

> The subject and all its gear become insubstantial, misty, and translucent. Its material armor (including natural armor) becomes worthless, though its size, Dexterity, deflection bonuses, and armor bonuses from force effects still apply. The subject gains DR 10/magic and becomes immune to poison, sneak attacks, and critical hits. It can't attack or cast spells with verbal, somatic, material, or focus components while in gaseous form. This does not rule out the use of certain spells that the subject may have prepared using the feats Silent Spell, Still Spell, and Eschew Materials. The subject also loses supernatural abilities while in gaseous form. If it has a touch spell ready to use, that spell is discharged harmlessly when the gaseous form spell takes effect.
>
> A gaseous creature can't run, but it can fly at a speed of 10 feet and automatically succeeds on all Fly skill checks. It can pass through small holes or narrow openings, even mere cracks, with all it was wearing or holding in its hands, as long as the spell persists. The creature is subject to the effects of wind, and it can't enter water or other liquid. It also can't manipulate objects or activate items, even those carried along with its gaseous form. Continuously active items remain active, though in some cases their effects may be moot.

except it obscures vision like this:

> A bank of fog billows out from the point you designate. The fog obscures all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. A creature within 5 feet has concealment (attacks have a 20% miss chance). Creatures farther away have total concealment (50% miss chance, and the attacker can't use sight to locate the target).
>
> A moderate wind (11+ mph) disperses the fog in 4 rounds; a strong wind (21+ mph) disperses the fog in 1 round.
>
> The spell does not function underwater.

Putting the correct parts of all three together, as indicated by the text, we get the prolix description of the ability:

> **Shadowy Mist Form**(*Sp*): At 10th level, a stygian slayer can transform itself and all its gear become an inky, insubstantial, black cloud of mist. Its material armor (including natural armor) becomes worthless, though its size, Dexterity, deflection bonuses, and armor bonuses from force effects still apply. The subject gains DR 10/magic and becomes immune to poison, sneak attacks, and critical hits. It can't attack or cast spells with verbal, somatic, material, or focus components while in gaseous form. This does not rule out the use of certain spells that the subject may have prepared using the feats Silent Spell, Still Spell, and Eschew Materials. The subject also loses supernatural abilities while in gaseous form. If it has a touch spell ready to use, that spell is discharged harmlessly when the gaseous form spell takes effect. The mist obscures all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. A creature within 5 feet has concealment (attacks have a 20% miss chance). Creatures farther away have total concealment (50% miss chance, and the attacker can't use sight to locate the target).
>
> A gaseous creature can't run, but it can fly at a speed of 10 feet and automatically succeeds on all Fly skill checks. It can pass through small holes or narrow openings, even mere cracks, with all it was wearing or holding in its hands, as long as the spell persists. The creature is subject to the effects of wind, and it can't enter water or other liquid. It also can't manipulate objects or activate items, even those carried along with its gaseous form. Continuously active items remain active, though in some cases their effects may be moot.
>
> The slayer can use this ability for a number of minutes per day equal to his level. These minutes need not be consecutive, but must be used in 1-minute increments. This ability replaces the advanced slayer talent gained at 10th level.

Among other things, this should clarify the the sytgian slayer's mist form is not the size of a *Fog Cloud* spell's area of effect.